# Deduplication by two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

1I need to deduplicate a table like this:-

```
name | fix | mobile
-----+-----+---------
dan  | 1   | 1
jon  | 1   | 3
mia  | 1   | 4
ken  | 5   | 4
```

I want to get:-

```
dan  | 1   | 1
jon  |     | 3
mia  |     | 4
ken  | 5   |
```

It is possible with Excel, but for 500k rows I get `'not responding'`
Access remove entire line if find a duplicate.

ex:
 set the primary key on fix, I get:-

```
dan  | 1  | 2
ken  | 5  | 4
```

set the primary key on `mobil`, I get:-

```
dan  | 1  | 1
jon  | 1  | 3
mia  | 1  | 4
```

Can SQL or another program do this? I have tried to use distinct or group by, but I didn't found the right formula.

Comment: So u want to return null instead of duplicate values? What is the reason of such question and is it important which name will save the value?

Comment: yes, null instead duplicates. it does not matter which name will be kept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible in sql. I did write sql code.let's say you have id column in table and  your table name is **people**. I wrote code for updating '**fix**' column. The trick is joining the table with itself. 
If you have any question feel free to ask.

```
    update temp1 set temp1.fix='' 
    from people temp1 inner join people  temp2 
    on temp1.fix=temp2.fix where temp1.id>temp2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME,
    IIF(t.partRankFix = 1, t.fix, NULL) AS fix,
    IIF(t.partRankMobile = 1, t.mobile, NULL) AS mobile
    ,A.field1, A.field2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        A.Name, A.Fix, A.mobile
        , Sum(IIF(A.fix = B.fix OR A.fix=B.mobile, 1, 0)) AS partRankFix
        , Sum(IIF(A.mobile = B.mobile AND A.mobile = B.fix, 2, 
              IIF(A.mobile = B.mobile OR A.mobile = B.fix, 1, 0))) AS partRankMobile
        , A.field1, A.field2
    FROM 
        yourTable AS A, 
        yourTable AS B
    WHERE 
        (((Nz(A.fix, 0) < Nz(B.fix, 0)) OR (Nz(B.fix, 0) = Nz(A.fix, 0))) AND (Nz(B.NAME, 0) >= Nz(A.NAME, 0)))
    GROUP BY 
        A.Name, A.Fix, A.mobile, A.field1, A.field2) AS t
```

Comment: @user2284877 I change `<=`  to `>=` ;).

Comment: same problem. see the question sample.

Answer (score 1):

This module should do the job. I have used a copy of your original table(here I named it `table1`) named dedup

```
Public Function Dedup()
Dim rstSource As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstDestination As DAO.Recordset
Dim deduppreviousValue As Long
Dim dedupValue As Long
Dim blnInit As Boolean

Set rstSource = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from Table1 order by Fix,Mobile")
Set rstDestination = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dedup")

With rstSource
    .MoveFirst
    blnInit = False
    While Not .EOF
        dedupValue = .Fields("fix")

        rstDestination.AddNew
        rstDestination.Fields("NameID") = .Fields("nameID")
        If Not blnInit Then
            rstDestination.Fields("fix") = .Fields("fix")
            blnInit = True
        Else
            If deduppreviousValue <> dedupValue Then
                rstDestination.Fields("fix") = .Fields("fix")
            Else

            End If
        End If
        rstDestination.Fields("mobile") = .Fields("mobile")
        rstDestination.Update
        deduppreviousValue = .Fields("fix")
        .MoveNext
    Wend

End With
End Function
```

Comment: As it is it works for putting in a module and running it ...or else put the body of the function in the click event of a form button

Comment: just call it from the click event of a button...like this     `Private Sub Command0_Click()`   
`Dedup`  
`End Sub`

Comment: you need to create an empty table dedup....just copy paste your source table keeping only the structure

Comment: can you give me more info?

Comment: just adjust the code for the 3rd column...it didn't saw it you wanted to nullify the 3rd column.....quick and dirty make a 2nd function like dedup and change from `fix` to `mobile` and remember to use .Edit instead of .AddNew...if you have trouble let me know...

Comment: I am not sure about the "overflow"...unless i have the data i can't help ....there could a lot of reasons....500K are not a lot of records....i have tables with millions of records.....

Comment: this is the even more quick and dirty solution..:).......discard the comment about .AddNew and .Edit .....use the same code just change the field from "Fix" to "mobile" on the 2nd run

Comment: use the Nz() function

Answer (score 0):

Ok I reached it with this example.

-First I create a table to work with:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (field1 INT, field2 INT, field3 int)
```

-Then I fill the fields with data similar to yours:

```
 INSERT INTO #Table VALUES(1,2,3)

 INSERT INTO #Table VALUES(2,2,4)

 INSERT INTO #Table VALUES(3,2,5)

 INSERT INTO #Table VALUES(4,3,5)
```

-Finnally with the query below you can reach what your look for:

```
 SELECT t1.field1,t2.field2,t3.field3 from  #Table t1 
 left join 
 (select field2,min(field1) AS field1 from #Table group by field2) t2 
 on t1.field1 = t2.field1  left join 
 (select field3,min(field1) AS field1 from #Table group by field3) t3 
 on   t1.field1 = t3.field1
```

The key is to make a left join with the same table for each field you wanna deduplicate always matching with the same field "field1".
In each of this tables you have to group by the field that you want to deduplicate.

Hope it helps.